# R dismo::gbm.step parameter selection function in parallel

Tags: r, loops, parallel-processing, r-caret, gbm

I have a working function that is coded to optimize parallel processing (hopefully). I am still not the most proficient with `R`, especially functions and iterating.

I was hoping someone out there could help me optimize the function I have written along with the extra code to aid in computing time and fully optimize the parallel processing options.

Specifically using `%do%` vs `%dopar%` and moving the additional code and parallel processing functions inside of the function. I cannot seem to get `%dopar%` to work and I am not sure if it is an issue with my code, `R` version, or conflicting libraries.

I would *greatly appreciate* any suggestions on possible ways to get the same results in a more efficient manner.

**Background:**

I am using `dismo::gbm.step` to build `gbm` models. `gbm.step` selects the optimal number of trees through k-fold cross validation. However, the parameters for tree complexity and learning rate still need to be set. I understand that `caret::train` is built specifically for this task, and I have had a lot of fun learning about `caret`, especially it's adaptive resampling capabilities. However, my response is binomial and `caret` does not have the option to return AUC for binomial distributions; I would like to use AUC to replicate similar published studies in my field (ecology).

I am also using `dismo::gbm.simplify` later in the analysis to identify possible reduced models. `gbm.simplify` relies on data created when building models in `dismo` and I cannot get it to work on models built in `caret`.

Finally, most of the `gbm` literature in ecology follows the methods described in Elith et al. 2008 "[A working guide to boosted regression trees](http://ibis.colostate.edu/WebContent/download_files/Elith_AWorkingGuideToBoostedRegressionTrees_2008.pdf)", which is what the BRT functions in `dismo` are based on. For the purposes of this study, I would like to keep using `dismo` to build `gbm` models.

The function I wrote tests several combinations of `tree.complexity` and `learning.rate` and returns a list of several performance metrics for each model. I then combine all of the `lists` into a `data.frame` for easy sorting.

**Goal of of the function**

1. Create a `gbm` model from each iteration of `tree.complexity` and
   `learning.rate`.
2. Store `$self.statistics$discrimination`,
   `cv.statistics$discrimination.mean`, `self.statistics$mean.resid`,
   and `cv.statistics$deviance.mean` in a `list` for each `gbm` model
   created.
3. Remove each `gbm` model to save space.
4. Combine each of the lists together into a format that enables easy sorting. Then remove each list.
5. Do all of the above in a manner that optimizes parallel processing as well as reducing computing time and memory used.

**Reproducible example** 
Using the `Anguilla_train` dataset from the `dismo` package

```
#Load libraries
require(pacman)
p_load(gbm, dismo, TeachingDemos, foreach, doParallel, data.table) 

data(Anguilla_train)

#Identify cores on current system
cores<-detectCores(all.tests = FALSE, logical = FALSE)
cores

#Create training function for gbm.step
step.train.fx=function(tree.com,learn){
  #set seed for reproducibility
  char2seed("StackOverflow", set = TRUE)
  k1<-gbm.step(data=Anguilla_train, 
               gbm.x = 3:13, 
               gbm.y = 2,
               family = "bernoulli", 
               tree.complexity = tree.com,
               learning.rate = learn,
               bag.fraction = 0.7,
               prev.stratify=TRUE,
               n.folds=10,
               n.trees=700,
               step.size=25,
               silent=TRUE,
               plot.main = FALSE,
               n.cores=cores)

  k.out=list(interaction.depth=k1$interaction.depth,
             shrinkage=k1$shrinkage,
             n.trees=k1$n.trees,
             AUC=k1$self.statistics$discrimination,
             cv.AUC=k1$cv.statistics$discrimination.mean,
             deviance=k1$self.statistics$mean.resid,
             cv.deviance=k1$cv.statistics$deviance.mean)  
  return(k.out)
}

#define complexity and learning rate
tree.complexity<-c(1:5)
learning.rate<-c(0.01,0.025,0.005,0.0025,0.001)

#setup parallel backend to use n processors
cl<-makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

#Run the actual function
foreach(i = tree.complexity) %do% {
  foreach(j = learning.rate) %do% {
    nam=paste0("gbm_tc",i,"lr",j)
    assign(nam,step.train.fx(tree.com=i,learn=j))

  }
}

#Stop parallel
stopCluster(cl)
registerDoSEQ()

#disable scientific notation
options(scipen=999)

#Find all item in workspace that contain "gbm_tc"
train.all<-ls(pattern="gbm_tc")

#cbind each list that contains "gbm_tc"
train.results<-list(do.call(cbind,mget(train.all)))

#Place in a data frame
train.results<- do.call(rbind, lapply(train.results, rbind))
train.results <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(train.results),ncol=7 , byrow=T))

#Change column names
colnames(train.results)<-c("TC","LR","n.trees", "AUC", "cv.AUC", "dev", "cv.dev")

#Round 4:7
train.results[,4:7]<-round(train.results[,4:7],digits=3)

#Sort by cv.dev, cv.AUC, AUC
train.results<-train.results[order(train.results$cv.dev,-train.results$cv.AUC, -train.results$AUC),]

train.results
```

Comment: caret **does** have the option to return AUC for binomial distributions. See `twoClassSummary`. However, it is not easy to return statistics that are derived from the model object (and not froth holdout set).

Comment: @topepo Max, thank you for your reply. I was under the impression when `metric=ROC` the response can be binomial, but must be a factor. When using `predict` won't this return a strictly binary outcome (e.g. 0 or 1) or am I incorrect? I was following one of your great walkthroughs where you apply this to the `mutagen` data set, but cannot find which one right now.  I would like to return a positive proper fraction between 0 and 1; I should have mentioned this is for a species distribution model. Also, I suppose if I have too many `caret` specific questions I may need to start a new question.

Comment: Did you finally manage to optimise this? I am looking for the same solution but with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to work out how to do this myself, and you've gotten a lot further than me! One thing that occurs to me is that the problem might be in the nested `%do%`s? As a test, why not try `%dopar%` only for `j`, or see if you can collapse your `j` & `k` matrix into a single vector, possible a list containing the permutations of both terms, to be passed to `gbm.step`? E.g.

```
tree.complexity = i[1],
learning.rate = i[2],
```

Please let me know if you have any success!

Edit: also, another potential route would be `%:%` from [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-wonders-of-foreach/).

```
foreach(tree.com = 1:5) %:% foreach(learn = c(0.01,0.025,0.005,0.0025,0.001)) %dopar% {
gbm.step ... return(list(...))}
```

If you added `tree.com` & `learn` to the list then potentially it would spit out a nice matrix of those values. Another option:

```
foreach(tree.com = 1:5, learn = c(0.01,0.025,0.005,0.0025,0.001) %dopar% {
    gbm.step ... return(list(...))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using some of your code here and also from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433821/building-parallel-gbm-models-using-cross-validation-in-r)

```
p_load(gbm, dismo, TeachingDemos, foreach, doParallel, data.table)
          
#Create grid of hyperparameter and variable combinations  
hyper_grid <- expand.grid(learning.rate = c(0.00005,
                                            0.00001,
                                            0.0005,
                                            0.0001,
                                            0.005,
                                            0.001,
                                            0.05,
                                            0.01,
                                            0.5,
                                            0.1),
                          tree.complexity = seq(1, 3, 1),
                          bag.fraction = seq(0.2, 0.8, 0.05)
            )
            
#Set up cluster to run in parallel
ncores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(ncores, outfile="FullGBMGridSearchListening.txt")
registerDoParallel(cl)
            
#Run grid search. Be warned, depending on how granular your grid is, this can take a very long time to run despite the higher efficiency of parallelisation.
system.time(hyper_grid_res <- foreach (i=1:nrow(hyper_grid),.packages=c('gbm','TeachingDemos','data.table'),.combine = rbind) 

%dopar% {
                
char2seed("reproducibility", set = TRUE)#sets the seed for reproducibility
                
# train models
gbm.tune <- gbm.step(data=mod.data, 
                     gbm.x = 3:13,
                     gbm.y = 2,
                     family = "bernoulli",
                     tree.complexity = hyper_grid$tree.complexity[i], 
                     learning.rate = hyper_grid$learning.rate[i],
                     bag.fraction = hyper_grid$bag.fraction[i], 
                     max.trees = 20000,
                     verbose = FALSE, 
                     silent = TRUE,
                     plot.main = FALSE)
                
#Extract the info we need for model ranking
tree.complexity <- hyper_grid$tree.complexity[i]
learning.rate <- hyper_grid$learning.rate[i]
bag.fraction <- hyper_grid$bag.fraction[i]
n.trees <- gbm.tune$n.trees
CV_correlation <- gbm.tune$cv.statistics$correlation.mean
CV_deviance_explained <- (((gbm.tune$self.statistics$mean.null- gbm.tune$cv.statistics$deviance.mean)/gbm.tune$self.statistics$mean.null)*100)
                
print(i)#Keep track of progress in listener
                
#Combine desired outputs in a data.table
data.table(tree.complexity = tree.complexity,
learning.rate = learning.rate,
bag.fraction = bag.fraction,
n.trees = n.trees,
CV_correlation = CV_correlation, 
CV_deviance_explained = CV_deviance_explained)
}
)

stopCluster(cl)
            
#Order by deviance explained > number of predictors > n.trees > tree.complexity and place into a new object (I recommend saving this as .csv for subsequent use)
            
Full_BRT_parallel_grid.search.results <- hyper_grid_res %>% dplyr::arrange(desc(CV_deviance_explained),desc(n.trees),tree.complexity)
```